# error in abstract should be compatible with

Tags: php, laravel

I have abstract class something like this

```
protected function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //function body
}
```

and extended class like

```
protected function update(PageRequest $request, $id)
{
    //function body
}
```

injected `PageRequest` extended from Request

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Helpers\Helpers;
use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class PageRequest extends Request
{
    //function body
}
```

I get this error

> Declaration of App\Http\Controllers\PagesController::update() should
>   be compatible with
>   App\Http\Controllers\MasterController\CrudController::update(App\Http\Requests\Request
>   $request, $id)

I know to pass all of the arguments and  access same for update() methods and I think I do it correctly.

Comment: PageRequest extended from Request ,,, @Med

Comment: Check your namespaces, could you post the tops of your class files?

Comment: See the answer below, use interface in order to inject a PageRequest

Comment: check comment comments of answer blow @Med

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct way to do this:

```
class Request implements RequestInterface
class PageRequest extends Request
```

And the function :

```
protected function update(RequestInterface $request, $id)
```

Comment: class `App\Http\Requests\Request` extended from `FormRequest` not `RequestInterface`

Comment: Your function update NEED a Request object. This can be fullfilled only by giving a Request object, even if PageRequest extends Request, it will fail. That's the reason why you can use interface

Comment: What @Med suggests is to create the `RequestInterface` (it can declare some of the methods of class `Request` but it doesn't need to do it, it can be empty as well) and implement this interface in the base class (if it is empty, the "implementation" reduces to the declaration `implements RequestInterface`). Then use the interface as the argument of function `update()`. This way you can overload the method in the children classes without changing its signature.

Comment: Wouldn't have explain this better @axiac

Comment: i try it but i think we cant change anything in object overriding i still  getting same error

Answer (score 1):

The best solution is to use an interface, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30614659/4265352).

Another solution is to declare the method `update()` in the child class without changing its signature and verify in the code that the argument has the correct type.

Something like this:

```
protected function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    if (! $request instanceof PageRequest) {
        throw new \InvalidArgumentException('Unexpected type ('.get_class($request).') of argument $request. Expecting an object of type PageRequest.');
    }

    // Do whatever you need to do with $request here
    // It is an object of type PageRequest
}
```

This solution has its own advantages in some contexts but it makes the code more verbose and adds extra code to run.